# Creating trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, database-trigger

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL

Table `A` : https://2.pik.vn/201819cbcc97-8d59-4d3f-9e47-38b5e33d00df.jpg

Table `B` : https://2.pik.vn/20186c925ba2-7c9c-4253-ba28-497df1465b4f.jpg

I want to create a trigger in PostgeSQL so if I update value in column `area` in table `A`, the value in `area_LUA` will automatically change in table `B`.

`area_LUA = total sum (area)*100` with condition `A.parent_id = B.parent_id and CODE ='LUA'`

Can someone guide me how to create a trigger like this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following trigger should get the job done.

Trigger `area_lua` will execute after each update on table `A`. Trigger function `update_area_lua` checks if the value of `area` changed, and accordingly updates column `area_LUA` in table `B`, with respect to the given `parent_id`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_area_lua()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.area <> OLD.area THEN
        UPDATE B
        SET area_LUA = (
            SELECT SUM(area) * 100 
            FROM A 
            WHERE parent_id = B.parent_id AND CODE ='LUA'
        )
        WHERE parent_id = NEW.parent_id;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$


CREATE TRIGGER area_lua
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON A
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_area_lua();
```